# Required tf for overlaying laser on image using Camera display type

Tags: rviz, laser, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'd like to display laser scanner on captured image in rviz using Camera display type.
(as like http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Camera)

I have published following tf.

Also camera_info is properly published. Also image is okay.
I can see some axis on image but not laser line.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40812/required-tf-for-overlaying-laser-on-image-using-camera-display-type./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Provided the tf transforms are correctly set up and the scanner is outputting laser_scan data, this should work. A few things you could check:

- Check that [tf is working](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems)
- Do you see other visualization
  elements in the camera view? (i.e.
  the grid, the arrow pointer when
  giving a 2D nav goal etc.)
- Have you set the fixed frame in rviz
  properly?
- Does it work with other robots/launch files? The Turtlebot or hector_quadrotor gazebo simulations for instance can be used to quickly check that.
- Is your camera calibrated correctly? The camera view rectifies images, so this has to be correct.
- Finally, be sure that you have set the "Overlay Alpha" of your camera view to something like 0.5.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-08-08**:
My fault was that the camera should be z-forward. :-)

**Comment by [danny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27512/danny/) on 2016-07-16**:
Hi, it passed quite a while.. anyway. I guess I'm facing the same problem. How did you finally solved the "z-forward camera" thing?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-16**:
[REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) specifies that the coordinate frame reported by a camera should have the z-axis of the frame pointing in the direction that the camera is looking.